# Separating caller in common object file

Tags: c++, c, linker, runtime

I am Working on an application which consists decoder and an encoder, the hierarchy is like this:

debug_info.h is included by both the encoder and decoder. After compilation, either encoder or decoder can be executed depending upon the usecase.
I want to separate the caller in debug_info.h means at run time i could be able to separate whether encoder is calling it or decoder.

My approach:

i enabled separate flags(dec_enable and enc_enable) in decoder and encoder make file.

I put a check on them debug_info.h

```
#ifdef dec_enable
//---Do Something--
#else
//--Do Something else
```

This is not working. Actually it shouldn't be because at run time only we will come to know which is getting executed.

Can you please tell me how to differentiate these two at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are actually making a debugger, your program design seems weird. Why would any algorithm in your program depend on some kind of debug file, which is likely not going to be included in production code? That's just a strange, tight coupling which shouldn't exist.

You should design the program so that the encoder/decoder algorithms know nothing except their designated task. Your debug file then includes the encoder/decoder.

If you need to change which function that is called in run time, simply write a plain if-else statement. Or if you for some reason need the code to be more generic, you can use function pointers, even though there seems to be no obvious need for that in this case.